# How can I create a registry diff patch?

Tags: regedit

I exported my Windows registry before and after launching a particular program. The two output *.reg files were both around 600MB, using BeyondCompare I was able to view the subtle differences.

What I want to be able to do next is create a patch *.reg file I can apply that only applies the different registry changes found in the before and after *.reg files. What would be the best way to do this?